# Hibernate reverse engineers (oracle) NUMBER to zero-precision big_decimal

Tags: oracle, hibernate, reverse-engineering, derby

When reverse engineering a column in an Oracle view with data type "NUMBER", the resultant column in `*.hbm.xml` is a `big_decimal` with `precision="0"`.

I also use these mapping files with Derby to do acceptance tests, but from the [Derby docs](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj132.html):

> The precision must be between 1 and 31.

I do not have control over the definition of the view. I read through the [reverse engineering docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/7.1/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/reverseengineering.html) and I can't see a way of controlling the precision.

How do I instruct hibernate to give me a valid (derby) precision?

Answer (score 0):

you should modify **hibernate.reveng.xml** as example below with your needs (precision,scale) and set output type (hibernate-type) then generate classess and mapping files.

```
    <hibernate-reverse-engineering>
           <type-mapping>
           <sql-type jdbc-type="NUMERIC" precision="1" scale="0" hibernate-type="boolean"/>
           <sql-type jdbc-type="NUMERIC" precision="22" scale="0" hibernate-type="long"/>  
           <sql-type jdbc-type="OTHER" hibernate-type="..."/>
           </type-mapping>
      ....
```

Comment: Setting these `type-mappings` don't affect the precision and scale values in the generated mapping files (`.hbm.xml`), but only the hibernate type of the column. Matching a `NUMERIC` with `precision="0"` will still result in a column in the `.hbm.xml` with `precision="0"`.